# Как масштабировать шрифты в адаптивной верстке?

Tags: html, css

Сейчас у меня установлено для `html` `font-size: 16px`, `h1 - 22px`. Как правильно прописывать их под разные размеры экрана?

Брать и вручную подгонять, нормально читается или нет? Может есть какие-то правила, например, что для размера `"768 - 992px"` будет нормально читаться и выглядеть шрифт `13px`.
Если я установлю ед. из. шрифтов в `rem`, то для моб. устройств от какого размера шрифта будут просчитываться значение в `rem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берем гибкую основу:

```
body {
    font-size:100%; /*  по-умолчанию 16px */
}

p {
    font-size: 1.25rem; /* 1,25rem относительно основы в 16px к body в результате даст размер шрифта в 16*1.25 = 20px */
}
```

> Чтобы изменить шрифт для более маленьких экранов с помощью
>   медиазапросов, достаточно просто изменить размер шрифта `body`, а так
>   как текст страницы масштабируется пропорционально ему:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        font-size:90%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        font-size:80%;
    }
}
```

**REM** - *относительный размер шрифта рассчитывается от корня страницы (Root EM), а именно — от тега HTML, а не от родителя. Меняя размер шрифта у HTML — все дочерние блоки так же меняют свой размер шрифта.*

Есть еще вариант с размерами относительно вьюпорта - `vw`, `vh`.

Вариант применения svg текста.

В сети достаточно информации по данному вопросу, стоит только поискать!

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте.
На мой взгляд самым верным решением будет указание размеров шрифтов для каждого разрешения экрана.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
font-size:12px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
font-size:13px;
}
```

Это позволит в случае необходимости быстро изменить размер шрифта. Также это гарантирует отображение размера шрифта согласно дизайну сайта.